# Converting File into XML Format

Tags: python, xml, txt, alteryx

Hello I have an Alteryx workflow that I edited and it was in XML format before, only problem is I didint have the option to export in XML.

There is a multitude of choices but went with the FLAT file since it looks close (let me know if there is a better one like json or htm I can use I have those options as well)

My issue is Alteryx now wont recognize this flat file as a workflow because the indentations are not there so Im guessing it cant tell the parents and so fort..

Now i have the exact same code in xml and flat with the exceptions of a few numbers changed nothing major.

Can I copy the indentations somehow from the source file to my new file? to make it xml same rows and everything or is there some sort of converter in notepad++

I appreciate the help here is a sample

```
          </RecordInfo>
    </MetaInfo>
  </Properties>
  <EngineSettings EngineDll="AlteryxBasePluginsEngine.dll" EngineDllEntryPoint="AlteryxDbFileInput" />
</Node>
<Node ToolID="423">
  <GuiSettings Plugin="AlteryxGuiToolkit.Questions.Tab.Tab">
    <Position x="0" y="0" width="59" height="59" />
  </GuiSettings>
  <Properties>
    <Configuration />
    <Annotation DisplayMode="0">
      <Name />
      <DefaultAnnotationText />
      <Left value="False" />
    </Annotation>
  </Properties>
</Node>
<Node ToolID="426">
  <GuiSettings Plugin="AlteryxGuiToolkit.Questions.FileBrowse.FileBrowse">
    <Position x="114" y="4640" width="59" height="59" />
  </GuiSettings>
  <Properties>
    <Configuration />




</RecordInfo>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
</MetaInfo>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
</Properties>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
<EngineSettings EngineDll="AlteryxBasePluginsEngine.dll" 
 EngineDllEntryPoint="AlteryxDbFileInput" />                                                                                                                                                                             
 </Node>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 <Node ToolID="423">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 <GuiSettings Plugin="AlteryxGuiToolkit.Questions.Tab.Tab">                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 <Position x="0" y="0" width="59" height="59" />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 </GuiSettings>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 <Properties>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 <Configuration />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 <Annotation DisplayMode="0">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 <Name />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 <DefaultAnnotationText />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 <Left value="False" />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 </Annotation>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 </Properties>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 </Node>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 <Node ToolID="426">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 <GuiSettings 
 Plugin="AlteryxGuiToolkit.Questions.FileBrowse.FileBrowse">                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 <Position x="114" y="4640" width="59" height="59" />                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 </GuiSettings>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 <Properties>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 <Configuration />
```

Answer (score 0):

XML does not require indentation at all, it is just sometimes there for readability.

It does require that all nodes are complete, eg this is OK

```
<a><b></b></a>
```

This is not:

```
<a><b></a></b>
```

Your sample is incomplete so I can't spot the problem, but it certainly can't start with an end tag - </RecordInfo>.

there are notepad++ XML plugins that identify errors in XML.

Comment: Gotcha yea it's just a snippet from the middle section of both files. So how can I convert a Flat asc file into xml format if it doesn't need indentation? Is there a python library I can use or a simple extension change ?

Comment: An XML file is a text file, so there is no conversion. If your file is not valid XML use notepad++ to find out where the error is.